# Receiving incorrect values from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to retrieve and use values from a JTable after a row has been selected using this code:

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
    TableModel tableModel = this.mainFrame.getViewersTableModel();
    this.mainFrame.setViewerButtonsEnabled(
        !((Boolean)(tableModel.getValueAt(e.getLastIndex(), 1)))
    );
}
```

In my scenario, the table has one row with a value of true, and another of false.

The very strange thing is that the *first time* I select a row, the value given is **correct**, whether it be the row holding true, or the one with false, but any subsequent selections result in getting true, no matter which row I pick.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging like displaying the row index? You can also use the `table.getSelectedRow()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it.

Instead of getting the required boolean in my event handler class, I just made a method in the mainFrame class that retrieves the boolean from the table. The issue is now resolved.

Thank you to all who helped.